# How to use values from variables imported from another file python

Tags: python, file, import

so I know this has been asked in several forms before, but I cannot relate to any of those, either I have something different or I just don't understand them.

The problem is I have script A and script B, and in script A I calculate and have all the variables I want to use in script B.

Script A has various functions, let's say for now I just want to pass a simple number from a variable in script A to script B , let's call the variable `value` .

I used `from script_A import value` .

Now, I have `value` initialized in script_A with 0 right at the top to say so, but script_A processes `value`, and gets a result clearly different from 0, but when I debug, I am getting in script_B `value == 0`, and not `value == calculated_value_that_should_be_there`.

I did not know what to do so I tough about scope,so I put it in the `return` of a function, I tried making variable `value` a Global variable. Nothing seems to work in the way that I am not passing the calculated 'value' but I am passing to script_B that 0 initialization.

P.S last thing I tried and what I saw from this topic is to import script_A as it was said with no namespaces. This has worked. When I write script_A.value it is calculated_value_that_should_be_there. But, I do not know why anything else that I described did not work.

```
script_A


from definitions import *
variable_1 = 0
variable_2 = 0
variable_3 = 0
variable_4 = 0 

total = 0
respected = 0

time_diff = {}
seconds_all_writes = "write"

class Detect():
    def __init__(self, data_manager, component_name, bus_name_list=None):

 def __Function_A(self):
       """
        global time_diff
        global seconds_all_writes

        process

script_B:
from script_A import respected
from script_A import total


import script_A

        print aln_mon_detector.total
        print aln_mon_detector.respected
```

I also want a dictionary

table_content.append(script_A.time_diff[file[script_A.seconds_all_writes])

I get

KeyError: 'writes'

Comment: Instead of describing your code can you please just paste some examples of the code that you are actually using? It would be a lot more helpful to debug it.

Comment: You'll need to use the `script_A_process` in your script B and get the returned value there. do, `from script_A import value, script_A_processs` and then do the process in script B. **Also, can you instead write down some code example, i'm not sure I got it right**

Comment: please edit your question to show the code you are using.

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

this sounds a bit confusing without an example, but, in principle, what you're trying to do should work. Have a look at a minimum example below.

ModuleA - defining the variable

```
# create the variable
someVariable = 1.

# apply modifications to the variable when called
def someFunc(var):
    return var + 2

# ask for changes
someVariable = someFunc(someVariable)
```

ModuleB - using the variable

```
import moduleA

# retrieve variable
var = moduleA.someVariable

print(var) # returns 3
```

Comment: yes, this works as I said in my P.S, but to the variables I transfer to script_B need to be declared as GLOBAL , I seem not to be able to access them in script_B if they are not global.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with immutability. Depends on what `value` is. If `value` is a list (that is, a mutable object) and you append to it, the change should be visible. However, if you write

```
from module import x
x = 5
```

you are not changing the actual value, so other references to `x` will still show the original object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `script A` like this:

```
# imports

value = 0
...  # some calculations
```

Re-organize `script A` as:

```
# imports

def main():
    value = 0
    ...  # some calculations
    return value
```

Now you can import `script A` in `script B` and run `calculations` inside `script B`:

```
import script_A

value = script_A.main()
```

That is how you should organize code pieces in Python.

Comment: I see, so initialize the value in main, not after the imports?

Comment: @whtr The point here is to create function `main()` (which returns calculation results) in `script_A` and then call function `scrit_A.main()` in `script_B` after importing `script_A`.